# Avoid to display the ValueField in the Grid Edit row editing

Tags: extjs, grid, gridpanel

I'm trying to edit the Gridpanel with the combobox items.
When I try selecting a value to edit  and click on the other cell the value field appears in the cell as seen in the image attached, I want to display the description of the items and keep the valueField hidden from appearing . How would I be able to show the description always and edit,update the panel. knowing that I can update the data with the id(valueField which is appearing in the second part of image) only.

please help. thanks in advance.

**Small piece of that grid**

```
{
            header: 'Field Time Distrib',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'feild_distributor',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank: true,
                displayField: "description",
                valueField: "distribsrcid",
                queryMode: 'local',
                mapperId: 'getfeildDistrib',
                lastQuery: '',
                forceSelection: true,               
                listeners: {
                    expand: function () {
                        var call = this.up('timegrid[itemId=feilddTimeGrid]').getSeletion().selection.record.data.fieldname.trim();
                        this.store.clearFilter();
                        this.store.filter({
                            property: 'call',
                            value: call,
                            exactMatch: true
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: this is the small screen shot]

Comment: not able to see the images.

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma updated...!!!!!!!!

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma Can you please look into this too!!! [Here....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409117/how-do-i-stop-a-clicked-combo-box-from-clearing-its-value)

Comment: In my example it is not clearing right

Comment: @SuryaPrakashTumma yes but it allows to add any values right?? that I want to restrict it. User should be able to select the values from the combo box itself.

Comment: I 've updated the question please look into that ... @SuryaPrakashTumma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can suggest you , Use renderer function of column identify if it is number ,If number get the respective name from the store  and return the name ...  check my fiddle.  [check the fiddle for my example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qoq)

Comment: Thanks Genius .. I apply this solution.

Comment: Note that this will only work when the data is loaded in the store, otherwise you would run into errors with records not being found. If using a remote store you would need to add a listener to refresh the grid when the store loads

Comment: There's one issue . When i click on the cell i gets reset to thye default that's null , I just want to retain the value selected on the last edit updated. How do i do that please?

Comment: Like i want to keep forceselction(true), yet retain the values