# How do I stop a clicked combo box from clearing its value?

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm trying to edit a combobox value. But what happens is when I click a grid cell **the old value disappears** I want to keep a the and also avoid the user to select the values form the **combo box itself and not values other than those in the drop down**

How can i achieve these two things.

```
{
    text: 'Food Items',
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    dataIndex: 'food_lister',
    flex: 1,
    renderer: function (value) {
        console.log()
        if (Ext.isNumber(value)) {
            var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
            return store.findRecord('foodid', value).get('fooddescp');
        }
        return value;
    },
    editor: {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        allowBlank: true,
        displayField: "fooddescp",
        valueField: "foodid",
        queryMode: 'local',
        mapperId: 'getfooddescrip',
        lastQuery: '',
        forceSelection: true,
        listeners: {
            expand: function () {
                var call = this.up('foodgrid[itemId=fooditemgrid]').getSelectionModel().selection.record.data.foodname.trim();
                this.store.clearFilter();
                //this.store.filter('call',call);
                this.store.filter({
                    property: 'call',
                    value: call,
                    exactMatch: true
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: As soon as I click that cell I data gets reset to null.How can i retain the already present data , without getting that to null]

[image: See this pic_new]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `editable : false` in combo  check the updated example

> [click here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qoq)

Edit: As per your comment if you still want to use editable true and restric the value other than the store you have to handle it in cell editing event `validateedit`

```
 plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    listeners: {
        validateedit: function( editor, context, eOpts ){
            var store = context.column.getEditor().store,
                record = context.record;
           if(store.find('id',context.value) === -1){
             context.cancel = true;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Above code is based on my example. Please check running example in my [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1qoq)

Comment: Yes. But, If i use `editale:false`   i won't be able to  type and get the related searches right? Like if the record is ECE, and and I just type 'E' it gives me the lists of items with E correct?,  Any possible Solution other than this

Comment: check the fiddle in the response

Comment: yes do this only for that that field by puting a conditon using context.field == 'dept' updated my example for your reference

Comment: Hai, Surya. What if i want to clear the cell and update it, Since we are giving the null value to be not trigger as changed. How do i Clear the cell with null value update. in the sense, Since the cell is null value allowed it takes null value too right, So how can i update that cell with the null value?

Comment: Basically this doesn't allow me to select the null value once i Select one value, Correct?, What if i want to select the null value that's the clear the cell whose value is already selctd..  Please Help me here

Comment: The way you are doing is not good John, To get answer for your query you are repeatedly accpeting and not accepting.

Comment: No No, That's not the case buddy. This worked perfectly for what was asked, but  there's this issue which emereged, Sorry if you felt offended. Bud

Comment: Hai Surya , I've added a modified fiddle with `forceSelection:true`
that resets the va;ue to null I've commented the `validateedit` listener , which disables us to enter a null value if after  selecting a item from the combo box we want to reset to null. Can you suggest me a solution. Would really appreciate this effort.

Comment: Hai Surya, Can you check on this please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920402/retain-the-already-present-value-of-the-cell-for-edit-on-click